# How can I properly implement a WebAPI web server with a sqlite database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, asp.net-web-api

So, I've been playing around with EF and Sqlite. I've managed to in my dev environment get them successfully able to read and write "Hello world" from and to a database. I'm using as I said Entity framework and the sqlite entity framework provider.

I'm reading that EF needs to be run in a single threaded environment. That entirely confuses me because to my understanding, web apps service multiple requests in parallel. How can a utility that needs to be single threaded possibly hope to be used in a web server?

If it matters, here is the console app I'm using to play around with the connection -- It also represents my current sum experience with EF

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var context = new SessionContext("SessionTables.sqlite"))
        {
            var session = new Session()
            {
                SessionID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B"),
                Domain = "NA",
                Username = "Sidney",
                Start = DateTime.UtcNow,
            };
            context.Sessions.Add(session);

            var action = new UserAction()
            {
                ActionDescription = "Tested Entity Framework",
                OccurredAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
            };
            session.Actions = new List<UserAction>();
            session.Actions.Add(action);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

public class Session
{
    public string SessionID { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserAction> Actions { get; set; }
}

public class UserAction
{
    public int UserActionID { get; set; }
    public string ActionDescription { get; set; }
    public DateTime OccurredAt { get; set; }
    public Guid SessionID { get; set; }
    public virtual Session Session { get; set; }
}

class SessionContext : DbContext
{
    public SessionContext(string filename)
        : base(new SQLiteConnection()
        {
            ConnectionString = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder()
            {
                DataSource = filename, ForeignKeys = true
            }
        .ConnectionString
        }, true)
    { /**/ }

    public DbSet<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserAction> Actions { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your confusing threading with instances.  That being said, you will have a max # of connections, so you will need to deal with that.

Comment: @Trey Do you mean to say I can have multiple instances of the DBContext object, as long as I don't interact with one instance in a cross threaded manner?

Comment: Cool name btw, mine too :-) anyhow read the answer below. He nailed it.

Comment: @Sidney, yes that's correct, just the general rule for any non-thread-safe object. That means: use a context per request (which an IoC container can help with), DON"T use a static context (people do that, you know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should not be a problem. Microsoft.Data.Sqlite from NuGet contains a version of SQLite that has been compiled with SQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 (Serialized).

Despite from this, there not seems to be any problem with EF that would make one suppose that the application should be "single-threaded".

Read please this document explaining the only limitations that you would have working with SQLite. As the document says:

> When using the SQLite provider, there are a number of limitations you
>   should be aware of. Most of these are a result of limitations in the
>   underlying SQLite database engine and are not specific to EF.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/limitations